# Assign point to nearest point based on distance table

Tags: sql, select

I have a table formatted as following:

```
FromTo  Time
a   z   1
c   z   2
d   z   3
e   z   4
a   y   2
c   y   1
d   y   3
e   y   4
```

All possible to locations are listed in this table (they all need to be assigned).
I would like to return the lowest (based on time) from-to combination for every to that exists. 
In the above the result should be:

```
a z 1
c y 1
```

This because one can travel faster from a to z than from a to y, etc... If there are 100 points to assign to 10 points, the result should be a table of 100 rows...

Comment: Your question doesn't make a lot of sense.  If you want to travel to `z` how is travelling to `y` a solution?  For the generic version of this problem, google for "traveling salesman problem".

Comment: Are you just looking for a query that gives you the rows where the `Time` column has the smallest value? There are a number of solutions for that already around. Google for something like "[query to get rows with smallest value](https://www.google.com/search?q=query+to+get+rows+with+smallest+value)". The most efficient solution will probably depend on which database you're using.

Comment: Andomar, I am well aware of the TSP. I never stated I wanted to travel to y, I want the shortest distances between all 'From' points to an individual To point. Paraphrased: I have x points that need to be assigned to y destinations.

@jpmc26 - Not entirely correct. I want to assign a row to a destination if and only if it has the lowest time between those points.

Comment: @FireFox So... you're looking for the rows with a minimum with some kind of `GROUP BY`? Group by what?

Comment: Group by 'from' In such a way that you can select the shortest route from every 'from' to a 'To'